# Conflict between mathax and wp-Typography

Tags: plugin-mathjax

Basically and the two plugins mentioned above installed and functioning. But in math posts, my math code is getting hyphenated, so I get mathjax errors like: `Undefined control sequence \righ` (the intended command was `\rightarrow`).

Searching I could not find anyone with a similar problem, so I resorted to the wisdom of SE :-) Ideas?

EDIT: here are the links for the plugins: [Mathjax-latex](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/) and [wp-Typography](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-typography/).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell wp-Typography to not process the code inside certain elements -- go to **Settings » wp-Typography** in your site's backend and add the appropriate items to the appropriate areas.  If you're not sure what the appropriate items are, have a look at the source of one of the pages where you've got some LaTeX code added in.  What tags are wrapped around your LaTeX code?

- `<math>...</math>` -- you should add `math` to the **HTML Elements** box
- `<div id="something">...</div>` -- add `something` to the **ID** box
- `<span class="something">...</span>` -- add `something` to the **Class** box

Comment: MathJax's html trickery turned out to be more complicated than I thought, so I can't make your suggestion to work. So far the only fix I have is to put the LaTeX commands that are being hyphenated into wp-Typography's list of words not to be hyphenated. This works, despite being notoriously crude...